# Slidify tables not displaying correctly when using revealjs framework

Tags: frameworks, r-markdown, pandoc, slidify

I'm trying to create a table (like the one below) using RMarkdown inside of the Slidify package.

```
Attribute    | Value
------------ | -------
Arribute1    | Value1
Attribute2   | Value2
Attribute3   | Value3
```

I had originally written the presentation using io2012 framework and my tables would display as [table using framework io2012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GahJ.png) after knitting.

However, after I switched to the revealjs framework, the tables no longer display in the correct format [table using framework revealjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkFKI.png)

I would like to use the revealjs framework for the final presentation but also need for my tables to show up as they do using the io2012 framework. Does anyone have tips on how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you'll have to identify the CSS that styled the tables in the old framework and copy that part of the CSS over to your HTML (e.g. your [pandoc template](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates))

Answer (score 0):

reveal.js uses a completely different CSS styling than io2012. I'm afraid you'll have to dig into the CSS and basically copy the table styles over.

You could try to use `knitr::kable` and `library(kableExtra)` and force the table into html (rather than markdown) `kable(df, "html")`, but you'd still have the issue of CSS.

Check the `.reveal table` stuff in the reveal.js CSS for a starter.